# How to remove "Remote desktop disconnected" window and close mstsc.exe

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, rdp, administration

I'm trying to manage user's RDP session at Windows Server 2003.
I have one Windows host. This host runs several user sessions.

```
c:>qwinsta

SESSIONNAME       USERNAME                 ID  STATE   TYPE        DEVICE
>console           Administrator           0   Active  wdcon
rdp-tcp                                    65536  Listen  rdpwd
rdp-tcp#1         test1                    1   Active  rdpwd
rdp-tcp#2         test2                    2   Active  rdpwd
```

Sometimes I need to close user's session and open it from the scratch.

`RWinsta %sessionID%` 
command works fine - user session is closed.

but I still have mstsc.exe process running and an opened window with the information "the remote session was disconnected because your session was logged off at the remote computer"

How could I close not only user session but mstsc process also?
Thank you.

Comment: So for now I'm using the next solution:
  1. I wrote an java application - it creates .rpd files for each user (user01.rdp, user02.rpd and so on) with the rdp settings inside (login, passwd, host..)

  2. run "mstsc.exe user01.rdp" - it creates rdp session and! the RDP  window title contains username "user01 - bla bla bla"

Now it is possible to filter mstsc.exe by username using "tasklist /FI WINDOWTITLE", and than I can logoff user and after that kill mstsc process.


Insane algorithm, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code and check if it works :

```
taskkill /PID /F
```

Try more options according to your requirement ,

Try `taskkill /?`

Comment: LOGOFF works similar to RWinsta command. It will logoff user but don't close mstsc.exe window.

Comment: The ID from the "qwinsta" command is not the same as the PID of the "mstsc.exe". We need to know the PID of the process, because we have 3-4 already running mstsc.exe process - and I'm unable to filter them by user name, all processes has the same attributes in "tasklist" command except PID.